# Как проверить, нашёлся ли элемент на странице

Tags: веб-программирование, html, javascript

С JS я слабый друг, поэтому хочу поинтересоваться:

В общем, нужно получить элемент на странице, имеющий вид:

```
<a id = "main" class = "nomodify" href = "/post*">
```

Где * - какое-либо число.

Дергаю его так:

```
var uid=parseInt(href.match(/\/post([0-9]+)$/));
```

Но теперь вот в чем проблема - проверить, нашлось ли искомое.

Как будет правильно это сделать?

Вот это сойдёт?

```
if (uid == null){
// что то там далее
}
```

Или как то по другому это дело делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам требуется только проверить, то лучше использовать метод [test](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp)

```
var patt = new RegExp("\/post([0-9]+)$");
if (patt.test(str)) {
    //do something
}
```

В других случаях, можно к примеру вот так:

```
var match = href.match(/\/post([0-9]+)$/);
if (match != null) {
    var uid = match[1];
}
```